# users#edit needs to be different depending on who views it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a website where people can subscribe to a service.

Currently, users#edit is for the users themselves to edit information like passwords.

However, I want admins to be able to visit the edit page to be able to edit things like `expiry_date`. Obviously users themselves can't be allowed to edit their own expiry date for the subscription, so I want to limit this only to admins. I'm thinking something like using `<%= if current_user.admin? %>` and putting the expiry date form fields into there is good enough, but am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

No, you're right. To make it simple, display the form field only if `current_user` is `admin`.

Create a method `admin?` in you `application_helper`.

```
def admin?
  current_user.admin?
end
```

And then in your form partial, add

```
<% if admin? %>
  <!-- display the field -->
<% end %>
```

However if you run into a situation where a lot of actions require only admins to view, I would suggest you to create a separate `namespace` for `admins`.

For more, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing